# how we send multiple values to server from android

Tags: http

```
public boolean setContacts(String name, String number) {

serviceUrl = "http://...../sample.php?method=setcontacts";

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("num", number));

    try {
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        httpPost = new HttpPost(serviceUrl);                
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                ..................

}
```

In this code i sending a single row having name and number to server its working fine,
but i want to send a list of name and number like

```
ArrayList<Strng[]> contactsList =...............;
```

so how i can implement this

```
 public boolean setContacts(ArrayList<String[]>  contactsList) {


 }
```

if you have any alternative way please suggest me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Serialize the information as a string and send it in the POST body. There are many ways to skin this cat, but the big 3 are:

- [Form encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application/x-www-form-urlencoded#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type)
- [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xml)
- [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json)